# How to remove white-space on the right from left-aligned dynamic length text?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, popover

I need the "foo bar hello world" text (or whatever length text / dynamic length) to be left-aligned but also not have white-space on the right.

[image]

My code:

```
<div style="padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 100px">
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
    <button style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [ngbPopover]="tipContent" placement="bottom" autoClose="outside">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #tipContent>
  <div style=" display:inline-block; height: 100%; width: auto; max-width: 100px;">
    <div style=" height: 100%; text-align: left; vertical-align: center;
                 overflow: hidden; max-width: 200px;">
      foo bar hello world
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I've created a stackblitz replicating my issue here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-popover-vs-tooltip-wbghhh?file=src/my-app.component.html

Comment: Your [mcve] needs to go in your question, not on a third party site.

Comment: I fixed my question, sorry about that

Answer (score -1):

@cfoxy17

instead adding max-width: 100px use max-width: auto

I added max-width: auto  and it is working fine see below stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-popover-vs-tooltip-4qnnkf?file=src/my-app.component.html

Comment: @cfoxy17 The previous stackblitz link was not correct, I corrected that now.